# Cannot Locate files inside Runtime Manager for Autoware.AI

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the documentation to use the LGSVL simulator with Autoware.AI from here:

https://www.lgsvlsimulator.com/docs/autoware-instructions/#setup

PS. I have followed the steps for the installation of docker and the shared-directory from the above link as well.

I navigate inside the Autoware folder by typing

```
cd Autoware.AI/docker/generic
```

Then I run the "run.sh" script by typing `./run.sh` and I get inside the autoware docker container. I then source the `install/setup.bash` file and start the run-time manager by typing `roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch`

After starting the run-time manager inside the docker, I am trying to load the files from autoware-data for the LGSVL simulator. However, the run-time manager is not able to locate any of these files from the shared-dir inside Autoware. (I have even tried to check the option for hidden files)

When I try to navigate to the folder "share-dir" from the command terminal, I can see the folder autoware-data and it contains all the files.

See the screenshot below for reference.

PS. The only files that the run-time manager cannot locate and use are from the below specified path:

```
/home/autoware/Autoware/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo
```

Any suggestions on why the run-time manager is not able to locate these files?

[image: image description]

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372864/cannot-locate-files-inside-runtime-manager-for-autoware.ai/) by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2021-03-01**:
If I remember well you should now have the dir `~/shared_dir` on the host machine as well. And you can put all the files you want to share with the container there.

**Comment by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on 2021-03-01**:
Yes, I have the dir `~/shared_dir` on the host machine as well, but I am unable to access that directory from within the run-time manager. I can only access the folders located within the container from the run-time manager. And for some reason, the `shared_dir` inside the container does not show any files when I access it from the run-time manager (as shown in the screenshots in my question)

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2021-03-01**:
`~/shared_dir` on host should be mounted in the docker container, also in `~/shared_dir`.
Put any file in the host `~/shared_dir` and you should find them in the docker container `~/shared_dir`.

**Comment by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on 2021-03-01**:
I have already put files in the host `~/shared_dir` and I am able to locate them inside the docker container from the **command line terminal.** But when I run the "**runtime manager"** and locate the files in the `Quick Start tab`, **they do not exist.** [even for the shared_dir inside the container]

**My issue is with loading the files from the runtime manager.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some troubleshooting with @shlokgoel, we found that this was caused by multiple instances of the Autoware.ai Docker containers running in the background. When you launch a Docker container which creates a shared volume (like the `shared_dir` folder in Autoware.ai), it binds the folder on your host to a directory in the container. If you then launch another container which attempts to bind to the same folder on the host, it will fail silently. The `shared_dir` folder will still appear in your container but it won't be attached to the host folder.

Resolution: When you are done working in an Autoware.ai Docker container, make sure to type `exit` and hit enter in the terminal in which you launched the container. Closing that terminal will leave the container running in the background.

You can verify if any containers are running in the background by running `docker container ls` in a new terminal. If there are any "detached" containers (meaning you don't have terminal access to them anymore), you can stop them with `docker container stop <container_name>`.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1